# Where does the expansion $x^\epsilon = 1 + \epsilon\log x + O(\epsilon^2)$ come from?

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series, mathematical-physics, gamma-function

In Folland's *Quantum Field Theory*, he states that for all small $\epsilon$ sufficiently close to zero we have that $x^\epsilon = 1 + \epsilon\log x + O(\epsilon^2)$ and $\Gamma(\epsilon) = \epsilon^{-1} -\gamma + O(\epsilon)$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function.

Where are these two expansions from, are they from some power series expansion? I do not recognize them.

Comment: The first one comes from $x^{\epsilon}=e^{\epsilon \log x}$ and Taylor series for $e^{x}$, the second one comes from the Weierstrass factorization for the gamma series

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta Thank you!

Comment: Is it not redundant to have terms $\epsilon$ and $O(\epsilon)$ both?  Should be $\Gamma(\epsilon) = \epsilon^{-1} -\gamma + O(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar You are correct, that is a typo. Thank you.

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: People keep citing Taylor's and power series, and here I am thinking this is just the definition of the derivative (at least in the first case).

Comment: @Arthur I think the definition of the derivative of $\epsilon\mapsto x^\epsilon$ at $0$ is a little weaker (with $o(\epsilon)$ instead of $O(\epsilon^2)$).

Comment: @AnneBauval You're right, it's not quite the definition. But if we do have a remainder term of class $O(\epsilon^2)$, then certainly we have a remainder term of class $o(\epsilon)$ as per the definition of the derivative.